# Js variable does not update in ajax

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, post, jstree

I use `jstree` and want to reload it with new data but I cannot send it to new data.

```
var $driver = 0;

$(document).ready(function () {
    $('#tree_folder').jstree({
        'core': {
            'check_callback': true,
            "themes": {
                "responsive": false
            },
            'data': {
                type: "POST",
                url: "Doc.aspx/Folder",
                data: function () { return '{"driver":"' + $driver + '"}' },
                contentType: "application/json"
            }
        }
    });
});        


$(document).on('click', '.tile', function () {
    var $item = $(this);    
    var $driver = $item.attr('data-driver');    
    //  alert($driver);    
    $('#tree_folder').jstree('refresh');
});
```

I got the new value when clicked, it send old default data every time. Above in alert function, it can give me the right value although `json` post send default one even data is written with function

`function () { return '{"driver":"' + $driver + '"}' }`

How can I get the new value from variable?

Comment: I think the issue might be json post is a async call, and you need to get the value in callback.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to return the response from an AJAX call?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14220321/how-to-return-the-response-from-an-ajax-call)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Remove `var` before `$driver` from `.tile click function` as you are `created global` previously,

Try this,

```
$(document).on('click', '.tile', function () {
    var $item = $(this);    
    $driver = $item.attr('data-driver');   // remove var from this line
    //  alert($driver);    
    $('#tree_folder').jstree('refresh');
});
```

Also use `cache:false` in `jstree` like,

```
function getDriver() {
    return '{"driver":"' + $driver+ '"}';
}

$(document).ready(function () {
    $('#tree_folder').jstree({
        'core': {
            'check_callback': true,
            "themes": {
                "responsive": false
            },
            cache: false, // cache false
            'data': {
                type: "POST",
                url: "Doc.aspx/Folder",
                data: getDriver(), // get updated driver
                contentType: "application/json"
            }
        }
    });
});
```

Also take a look on [change ajax options in jstree from server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6519747/change-ajax-options-in-jstree-and-reload-the-tree-from-server)

Comment: Thanks, How can I forget var in there (:, is it necessary `case:false` ? Because it works worked well witout it

Comment: ok, its not necessary. it is used for clearing cache data only.